# Javascript or jQuery need input field autogrow, but <td> or <div> need to be fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example 2 HTML rows. The first row is header. The second row is for input. Default width for all `<td>` is set.

User starts to type something in input fields. As length of tex is more than default width of `<td>` input field starts to autogrow.

Here is my example 
http://jsfiddle.net/rigaconnect/22Puw/2/

```
<tr>
<td width="20">1</td>
<td width="20">2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="20">
<input id="txt" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';"  style="width:20px;">
</td>
<td width="20">
<input id="txt" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';"  style="width:20px;">
</td>
</tr>
```

Problem is that `<td>` also autogrow.

Need that `<td>` always has default (fixed) width; grows only input field and as if goes over `<td>` on right.

Tried to set max width `<td style="max-width:20px;">` no solution.

Then tried this (for header `<td>`)

```
<td style="width: 20px; display: inline-block;">1</td>
<td style="width: 20px; display: inline-block;">2</td>
```

but in such case they are in vertical position (not horizontal).

Here http://jsfiddle.net/rigaconnect/RURYw/10/ is example how to do it with drop down fields. Need something similar with input fields.

Answer (score 0):

max-width works for me in Chrome and Firefox:
http://jsfiddle.net/22Puw/4/

```
td input {
      max-width : 20px; 
}
```

Comment: their width grows. Or we have a different opinion about what autogrow means.

Comment: Regarding http://jsfiddle.net/22Puw/4/ I mean when you type something in input field, the input field (and only this input field) becomes wider (as you type)...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the table to a fixed width by adding this to your CSS:

```
    table {
        table-layout:fixed;
        width:60px;
    }
```

Comment: With `table-layout:fixed;` input field does not autogrow

Comment: The input does autogrown, but the td stays fixed. You could add overflow:visible; to your td so your input over steps the td boundaries. But I would think of another layout, because your inputs will then be over one another

Comment: hmmm, please, see http://jsfiddle.net/rigaconnect/22Puw/5/ I added `table` css. All seems fixed